# Fit Laplace Distribution with specified mean or sigma

Tags: python, scipy

I want to fit the Laplace distribution to specific data. But I want the mean to be equal to 0.
I believe using the fit function in `scipy.stats` and then setting the mean (loc) parameter to zero is not the logical solution.
Is there any better solution? Thanks in advance.

```
from scipy.stats import laplace
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def fit_laplace(arr, axes):
    params = laplace.fit(arr)
    x = np.linspace(min(arr), max(arr), 100)
    print("PARAMS: ", params)
    pdf_fitted = laplace.pdf(x, 0, params[1])
    axes.plot(x, pdf_fitted, color='red')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To constrain the mean to be zero, use `floc=0` in the call of the `fit` method:

```
params = laplace.fit(arr, floc=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach is to first transform your data with [z-transform](http://www.statistics4u.info/fundstat_eng/ee_ztransform.html), then fit the distribution.

Comment: From that page: "In some published papers you can read that the z-scores are normally distributed. This is wrong - the z-transform does not change the form of the distribution, it only adjusts the mean and the standard deviation."

The Laplace distribution is definitely not Gaussian-shaped.